# Save files not under public/assets but under a different folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I have a Rails project.

My files are configured to be saved under `RAILS_ROOT/public/assets`.

Now we are moving to a new server, and I want all files to be read from and saved to a different folder. Let's say `/extra_drive`, that sits in a different folder than the Rails app (not even under `/var/www/html`).

How can i do that? With Apache? with configuring Rails?

Comment: When you say you have files to be saved, are these user uploads?

Comment: yes,, they are.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to utilize modern filesystem features such as [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) or bind mount.
So after moving the files to a new location (for example /extra_drive) you could create a symlink like

```
ln -s /extra_drive RAILS_ROOT/public/assets
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

In the asset.rb model I've changed the `has_attached_file`

From:

```
:url =>  "/assets/:month/:day/:name.:extension",
:path => ":rails_root/public/assets/:month/:day/:name.:extension"
```

To:

```
:url =>  "/user_files/:month/:day/:name.:extension", 
:path => "../../../../extra_drive/:month/:day/:name.:extension"
```

Then, in apache configuration file I added:

```
Alias "/user_files" "/extra_drive"
```